# NSOutlineView bug after expanding

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView with expandable items. When I expand an item, the newly displayed items are displayed fine. But when I then collapse it, and expand it again, I see this weird bug (see picture):
[image]

And it happens always with those same items. (The items contain just a simple NSTextField)

Did anybody come across something similar?

Do I maybe create the outlineview items wrong? I create them using;

```
let cellView = PlaylistTableRowView()
cellView.title.stringValue = playlistItem.title
return cellView
```

in the `func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView?` method.

Comment: A simple `NSTextField` is one line and the row height is fixed. Please tell us how to reproduce the issue in a new Xcode project.

Comment: Looks like an auto layout issue with your text - it's laying out to some reduced width. Can you fix your text width? Or look at content hugging and content compression for your text.